# QML Components Library

Tags: qt, dll, qml, qqmlcomponent

I've been trying to figure out how to create a .dll with only .qml files. To do that i've been looking all over Qt Documentation, nevertheless all my attempts have been unsuccessful.
I need a .dll file only, i don't want to make the .qml files to be accessible to the user.

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html i tried to compile and use the example but it did not worked, i tried to do one myself taking my .qml files but it did not worked aswell.

Does someone here could explain to me the workflow to accomplish this task with clear steps ? I realize that QML is still quiet new, and i assume this is why i couldn't find a proper example/documentation about that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Btw when i said i couldn't make it work it means i generated the .dll file but did not manage to import it in a Qt Quick Application

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the reply. I saw these posts, let's say i generated a .rcc file containing my QML files and i registered it in my main, how can i acess these qml components in my qml code now ? Unfortunately Qt documentation explain how to generate .rcc file but not how to use it afterwards.

Comment: Did you check my link? There is usage example in the answer.